# Getting a decimal cast out of a string

Tags: python, list, dictionary, casting, txt

I am trying to read a txt file into a list of dictionaries, but since some of the entries are casted decimals (which is the output of a function I can't change), when I read them out of the txt file, they are double stringed.

This is the code I am using for creating the list that I found on geeks for geeks:

```
damages = []
def parse(d):
    dictionary = dict()
    # Removes curly braces and splits the pairs into a list
    pairs = d.strip('{}').split(', ')
    for i in pairs:
        pair = i.split(': ')
        # Other symbols from the key-value pair should be stripped.
        dictionary[pair[0].strip('\'\'\"\"\"\"')] = pair[1].strip('\'\'\"\"\'\'')
    return dictionary
try:
    geeky_file = open('TowerA/0-deg-DamagesStates.txt', 'rt')
    lines = geeky_file.read().split('\n')
    for l in lines:
        if l != '':
            dictionary = parse(l)
            damages.append(dictionary)
            #print(dictionary)
    geeky_file.close()
except:
    print("Something unexpected occurred!")
```

One line of the list this makes is:
`{'DS_0': "Decimal('0.7180868594')", 'DS_1': '0', 'DS_2': '0', 'DS_3': "Decimal('0.2819131406')"}`

But, in order to run the next analysis method, the
`"Decimal('0.7180868594')"`
, has to be
`Decimal('0.7180868594')` without the external string quotation marks.

I tried stripping more of the quotations marks in the def parse, but that didn't help anything.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"Decimal('0.7180868594')"` is a string. What are you trying to do with it in the next analysis method?

Comment: Note that the parameter to `strip` is the set of characters to delete.  There is no point in duplicating things.  `.strip('\'"')` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your 'next analysis method' involves using Decimal from the decimal library module; this takes a number as a string. If so then maybe this is useful:

You **could** use the `eval` function on the whole string:

```
n = eval("Decimal('0.7180868594')")
```

However, eval has specific security drawbacks which you can look up.

Better to extract the string and use that:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import re

s = "Decimal('0.7180868594')"

m = re.search(r"(\d+\.\d+)", s).group(1)

n = Decimal(m)
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the second extraction method to update all of the strings in the list I had. Eval also worked with the next analysis method -- I am doing Catastrophe modeling with IN-CORE, and it has its own Python library for analysis, so everything has to be in the right format to input into the method's definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually splice the string like so:

```py
if value.startswith("Decimal('") and value.endswith("')"):
            value = Decimal(value[9:-2])
```

in `parse`. This is a pretty inefficient solution, but it should hopefully suffice for your purposes.